# Changed (Add, Delete) Items in ICollectionView with ObservableCollection as Source

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I'm making an application to view database data (many million rows) in a `DataGrid` with a Filter and Paging Control.

[image: DataGrid]

I'm getting the data in my ViewModel via EntityFramework 5 and bind the `DataGrid` to a `ICollectionView`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EntityView}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          Sorting="OnSortingGrid"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

`Reload()` is called if `Page`, `FilterString` or `SortString` is changed

```
public ObservableCollection<ProductShipment> SourceCollection
{
    get { return _sourceCollection }
    set { _sourceCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged("SourceCollection"; }
}
private ObservableCollection<ProductShipment> _sourceCollection;

public async void ReloadData()
{
    if (Context == null)
        Context = new DatabaseContext();

    await Task.Run(
        () =>
            {
                // Current set is something like
                var entitylist = Context.Where(FilterString)
                                        .OrderBy(SortString)
                                        .Skip(PageSize * Page)
                                        .Take(PageSize).ToList();

                if (SourceCollection == null)
                   SourceCollection = new ObservableCollection<ProductShipment>();

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    () =>
                        {
                            SourceCollection.Clear();

                            foreach (var entity in entitylist)
                            {
                               SourceCollection.Add(entity);
                            }

                            if (EntityView == null)
                            {
                                EntityView = new ListCollectionView(SourceCollection);
                            }

                            // Do Grouping if there is a Grouping Definition
                            ...
                        }, DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
            });

    //Exception/Success handling etc.
}
```

But the changes in the `SourceCollection` don't affect the `CollectionView`. I know I could just always asign a new `CollectionView` to `EntityView`, but then I would loose the Sorting on the DataGrid.

Is there a better way to handle this stuff with EntityFramework? Like binding the whole thing with lazy loading and then setting filters on the `CollectionView`?

Or is there a way to let the `EntityView` know the `SourceCollection` has changed?

Comment: What is the ObservableCollection is your code?

Comment: SourceCollection, I've now added it to the example so it's clearer

Comment: Another point : You should not do SourceCollection.Clear(). Handle the removal of items instead. And no need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged as you are using an ObservableCollection. ObservableCollection does implement INotifyPropertyChanged for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the list of entities directly to the ListCollectionView...

```
        ListCollectionView EntityView = new ListCollectionView(new List<ProductShipment>);
        foreach (var entity in entitylist)
        {
            EntityView.AddNewItem(entity);
        }
        EntityView.CommitNew();
        OnPropertyChanged("EntityView");
```

...and this will help get what you're after.  This eliminates your interim step of adding to a List.  Depending upon the memory demand, you MIGHT want to adjust your virtualizing parameters AFTER loading the LCV because the ItemsControlGenerator will by default select the most recent addition as the LCV's current item.  But that's a performance vs memory choice.

For your other question about how to let the LCV know if an underlying List has changed, you can

```
SourceCollection.CollectionChanged+=MyHandler;
```

And implement the handler to get the changes...

Comment: Looks promising, I will try that out!

Comment: This works even without `OnPropertyChanged`, but the DataGrid loses sorting when doing it with CommitNew()

Comment: You'll need to add the sort handler to your question

Comment: It's kind of complicated, best solution I've found was to add an eventhandler for Sorting build my own SortString from the DataGrid.Columns SortDescriptions and then get sorted entries from the database via dynamic linq. I haven't found a better way to use the sort description from the DataGrid to be used in the query.

Comment: what prevents you from using the built-in LCV collection of SortDescriptions?

Comment: when the user clicks on the DataGrid columns the SortDescription of the sort directions of the LCV are not changed, also when I set the SortDescription on the LCV the DataGrid doesn't change

Comment: Also I need to load new data from the database, because the currently visible data could change, when the sorting changes.

Comment: Wow.  That's a pretty big gap to your original question.  I suggest opening a new question on a more closely related theme.  Given what you wrote, there's not much more in this question I would expect.